# Permission error trying to instaling flutter

Tags: 19.04

I am trying to install [flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux):

```
cd ~/development
tar xf ~/Downloads/flutter_linux_v1.12.13+hotfix.5-stable.tar.xz
```

after extract the file, I update the path:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(pwd)/flutter/bin
```

but nothing happens here.

When I execute `flutter` in terminal I get the error:

```
Failed to open or create the artifact cache lockfile: "FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/home/dinushi/flutter/bin/cache/lockfile' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)" 
Please ensure you have permissions to create or open /home/dinushi/flutter/bin/cache/lockfile
Failed to open or create the lockfile
```

[image]

I tried to solve it using [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087025/permission-error-when-creating-flutter-project) but after I typed:

```
flutter precache
```

I got the same error.

I can't find any way to fix this, so I'd be glad if someone helps me :)

Comment: Just to be clear, try running `chown -R $USER /home/dinushi/flutter/` and if that doesn't work, try: `chown -R $USER:$USER /home/dinushi/flutter/`

Comment: I run those code and after I type flutter "~$ flutter
flutter: command not found
"

Comment: Does your PATH need to be exported again? `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"`

Comment: The `export` command is not permanent To make the change permanent, run the following command: `echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/home/dinushi/flutter/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: "cd ~/development
bash: cd: /home/dinushi/development: No such file or directory" may I want to create new floder name by development. :-( I still got that error "flutter
Failed to open or create the artifact cache lockfile: "FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path =
'/home/dinushi/flutter/bin/cache/lockfile' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)"
Please ensure you have permissions to create or open /home/dinushi/flutter/bin/cache/lockfile
Failed to open or create the lockfile"

Comment: flutter install first step is  "cd ~/development" that code, when I run this code "dinushi@pop-os:~$ cd ~/development
bash: cd: /home/dinushi/development: No such file or directory"

Comment: Sorry I took so long to get back. You do not need the `~/development` folder. It shows that `flutter` was extracted to your user's home directory and this is not a problem. Run the following command to fix the permission issue: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/dinushi/flutter` and then try to run flutter again. If you still have a problem, we can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to solve this problem is to start over.

First, delete your current flutter directory:

```
rm -r /home/dinushi/flutter
```

If you get a permission denied error, please post a comment to let me know.

Next, run the following commands to download and extract flutter to your user's home directory:

```
wget 'https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_v1.12.13+hotfix.5-stable.tar.xz'
tar xvf flutter*xz
```

Now, run your flutter commands:

```
flutter precache
```

Also, you can run the following command to tell you if you are missing any dependencies:

```
flutter doctor
```

Comment: thank you.... :-)))

Comment: @DinushiDhananjani Awesome! If this fixed your problem, please click the checkmark icon to the left of the answer to mark this as the solution. You can also upvote if you simply found the answer helpful. Thanks!